# What does 原地踏步 mean in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

Heard this on TVB: 原地踏步. What does the phrase mean? There's nothing in the Cantonese dictionary for this phrase.

Comment: The Perapera Chinese Pop-up Dictionary knows this phrase, as does the Yellowbridge Mandarin-English Talking Dictionary. Good resources.  As to paper, it is in the big 2000 page Oxford Chinese Dictionary.

Comment: The literal meaning in Chinese is **to step on the same position**, translated to English is **to mark time** in military training. The extended meaning is **no progress or improvement** on something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, 原地踏步 is not a Cantonese phrase, it's just a Chinese phrase.

The literal meaning is marking time, and it's often used to describe a situation that one doesn't make progress or fall behind.

> 班长命令战士们原地踏步.

The squad leader ordered the men to mark time.

> 我要么原地踏步直到获得晋升（这看来得是几年以后的事了），要么改变现在正做的事情。

I could either tread water until I was promoted, which looked to be a few years away, or I could change what I was doing.

Comment: cool thanks! but why 原地? the last two characters make sense.

Comment: Perhaps you've learned 原 as "field", but it has another meaning: "original".

Comment: Actually, 原 means original and 地 means field.

Answer (score 0):

原地踏步 basically means "going around in circles".